# How to sort 5000 contacts run below 5s in Android

Tags: android, algorithm, performance, sorting

I'm doing android contact sort algorithm.But now, my algorithm is very slow.About 5000 contacts in android run about 5 seconds. So i want to know more faster algorithm. Thanks!

Comment: search on google .

Comment: Please post your current sorting code.

Comment: Show us your implementation. Which sorting algorithm have you implemented? How often do you change the sorting criteria?

Comment: do not implement any custom sort algorithm, just use either `Arrays#sort` or `Collections#sort`

Comment: Yes,i use Comparator from Collection to sort.But i deal with my own business logic .

Comment: Maybe my business logic cases this problem.

Comment: post your code then

Comment: while using comparator, how are you managin hashcode ? That can have impact on performance

Comment: Voting to close because you haven't posted your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recomend `QuickSort` as it runs `O(nlogn)` and is the fastest sorting algorithm. Let me introduce you to `QuickSort`.

**Algorithm**

- Select one element in your array - call it pivot.
- All elements smaller than your pivot should be placed in one array, the rest in another,
- Apply quicksort for both arrays recursivly,
- combine partial results.

[Youtube Java tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mN5ib1XasSA)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it myself.

Comment: On StackOverflow we press UpArrow instead of saying thanks.

Comment: `Marge arrays`? No, to combine the partial results, it is not necessary to inspect each item from every partial result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Edited.